# JUCE: Not able to instantiate class "operate '=' does not match the operands"

Tags: c++, object, juce

I'm struggling with JUCE library because I'm following the GUI tutorials, 
and for some reason I can't use the "new instance" syntax inside the initialise function. Is there something context specific about this particular block that doesn't allow for the "new" operator to be used to instantiate the GUI window class?

```
 #include "../JuceLibraryCode/JuceHeader.h"
    #include "MainComponent.h"
    #include <iostream>

    /* Auto generated code*/

    class MyApplication: public JUCEApplication
    {
    public:
        //==============================================================================
        MyApplication() {}

        const String getApplicationName() override       { return ProjectInfo::projectName; }
        const String getApplicationVersion() override    { return ProjectInfo::versionString; }
        bool moreThanOneInstanceAllowed() override       { return true; }

        //==============================================================================
        void initialise (const String& commandLine) override
        {


            MyWindow.reset (new The_Main_Window (getApplicationName()));

            MyWindow = new The_Main_Window(getApplicationName()); //New instance syntax. 
        }

        void shutdown() override
        {
            // Add your application's shutdown code here..

            MyWindow = nullptr; // (deletes our window)
        }

        //==============================================================================
        void systemRequestedQuit() override
        {
            // This is called when the app is being asked to quit: you can ignore this
            // request and let the app carry on running, or call quit() to allow the app to close.
            quit();
        }

        void anotherInstanceStarted (const String& commandLine) override
        {
            // When another instance of the app is launched while this one is running,
            // this method is invoked, and the commandLine parameter tells you what
            // the other instance's command-line arguments were.
        }

        //==============================================================================
        /*
            This class implements the desktop window that contains an instance of
            our MainComponent class.
        */
        class The_Main_Window    : public DialogWindow
        {
        public:
            The_Main_Window (String name) : DialogWindow (name, Colours::beige,DialogWindow::allButtons)

            {
                setUsingNativeTitleBar (true);
                setContentOwned (new MainComponent(), true);
                setResizable (true, true);

                centreWithSize (300, 600);
                setVisible (true);
            }

            void closeButtonPressed() override
            {

                JUCEApplication::getInstance()->systemRequestedQuit();
            }



        private:
            JUCE_DECLARE_NON_COPYABLE_WITH_LEAK_DETECTOR (The_Main_Window)
        };

    private:
        std::unique_ptr<The_Main_Window> MyWindow; // what the heck does this guy do? 
    };

    //==============================================================================
    // This macro generates the main() routine that launches the app.
    START_JUCE_APPLICATION (MyApplication) // This guy generates the entry point?
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Also learn how to create a [mcve]. Lastly, when posting about errors, please include the *exact* errors you get, copy-pasted as text, in full and complete.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Actually, it's the hello world for JUCE, so a MCVE already.

Answer (score 1):

The unique pointer doesn't have an assignment operator for a new pointer (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/operator=). For that, you need `reset`.

Anyway, you did twice the same, and the second time is superfluous (the one with the assignment).

```
void initialise (const String& commandLine) override
{
    MyWindow.reset (new The_Main_Window (getApplicationName()));
}
```

Same for the shutdown:

```
void shutdown() override
{
    // Add your application's shutdown code here..

    MyWindow.reset(); // (deletes our window)
}
```

Comment: Okay. So I need create an assignment operator for the new pointer to allow the 'new instance' syntax?

Comment: No, you need to use the `reset` function to make a unique pointer point to an object as shown above.

Comment: Okay so the reset operator isn't part of JUCE? It's part of unique pointer? Should I use something other than unique pointer to get the job done?

Comment: No, that's the recommendations for JUCE to use the unique pointer. Change the code as I've shown you. Learn C++11 as well.